# Override an struts 2 interceptor

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor, struts2-interceptors

We are using the `store` interceptor. In some rare cases it happens that this interceptor throws `Session Already Invalidate`  exception, while try to put error messages in session (`MessageStoreInterceptor` line: 282).

I tried to override this interceptor and silently shallow the exception, and let the action be executed.

It seems to be simple but I can not find what should I return when exception happens ( how do I get the next interceptor?!) :

```java
public class MyMessageStoreInterceptor extends MessageStoreInterceptor {

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

        try{
            return super.intercept(invocation);
        }catch(IllegalStateException ex){
            return ??; 
        }

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get to the next interceptor you should return `invocation.invoke()`. It returns an action result. If you didn't get a result due to the exception, and you want to continue the action invocation, you should return your own result or one of the predefined results such as `SUCCESS` or `ERROR`.

```java
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

    try{
        return super.intercept(invocation);
    }catch(IllegalStateException ex){
        return Action.ERROR; 
    }

}
```